# Elasticsearch ngram boost substring matches beginning or near beginning of the string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this ngram setting:

```
"settings": {
"max_ngram_diff": 20,
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "ngram_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "filter": "lowercase",
      "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "ngram_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 3,
      "max_gram": 20,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit",
        "whitespace",
        "custom"
      ],
      "custom_token_chars": "-:."
    }
  }
}
```

To analyze SSN and randomgenerated numbers.

```
"SSN": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
},
"RandomGenNumbers": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
}
```

When searching on both fields like this:

```
{
    "match": {
        "RandomGenNumbers": {
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
            "query": "199"
        }
    }
},
{
    "match": {
        "SSN": {
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
            "query": "199"
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to get SSN: 199012121234 first before RandomGenNumbers: 23381990. But I'm getting RandomGenNumbers first with 7.6 score while SSN had 3.1 in score.

When I explain the search result it seems like it got higher score because there are more documents with the field (N) and less on terms (n) if you look in the (idf) formula?

```
"value" : 7.617782,
"description" : "weight(RandomGenNumbers:199 in 6588) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
"details" : [
{
"value" : 7.617782,
"description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
"details" : [
    {
    "value" : 2.2,
    "description" : "boost",
    "details" : [ ]
    },
    {
    "value" : 6.359767,
    "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
    "details" : [
        {
        "value" : 134,
        "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
        "details" : [ ]
        },
        {
        "value" : 77755,
        "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
        "details" : [ ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

Here is the SSN with lower score:

```
"value" : 3.146309,
"description" : "weight(SSN:199 in 6131) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
"details" : [
{
    "value" : 3.146309,
    "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
    "details" : [
    {
        "value" : 2.2,
        "description" : "boost",
        "details" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "value" : 2.2155435,
        "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
        "details" : [
        {
            "value" : 6938,
            "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
            "details" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "value" : 63600,
            "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
            "details" : [ ]
        }
        ]
    }
```

Same when searching "990".
Is there a way to boost substring closer to the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 0):

The score is higher whenever the query makes a more substantial portion of the term. In your case, `199` is 3/8 of `23381990` but only 3/12 of `199012121234` so first is rated higher.

To boost matches at the beginning of the term you can use a boosted query with regex `199.*` (slower searches) or [edge n-grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) subfield (larger indices, slower indexing). If the performance is ok, you could use regex for "near-beginning" matches as well, otherwise you might need to use some more edge-ngram fields and populate them on indexing removing one or few leading characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are there any example on this? Does edge ngram only work if the string matches the first char? like 199,1990.... how about searching for 990? Does it mean i need to implement lower boost for each char away from the beginning?
199.* with e.g. 5 boost then 990 with 3 boost and so on?

Comment: Basically what both ngram and edge-ngram tokenizers do is producing multiple tokens from the string but instead of splitting string into words it prepares "slices" or substrings (all of them for ngrams and only ones starting from 0 for edge-ngrams). As you can imagine, these might take a lot of space when stored and indexed but other than that they are just usual tokens so matching will be plenty fast.

Comment: With regexp query, unlike that, you still store your strings like `keyword` unanalyzed tokens but on query time ES does a "full scan" over all tokens to check which ones match so it's much slower but also more powerful. So you can do a query which would match `199.*` (boosted by 10),  `.199.*` (boosted by 8), `..199.*` (boosted by 6), `...199.*` (boosted by 4) etc. Though, similarly to SQL world, these full scans will be quite expensive.

Comment: To get quick result is important for me so im not so sure with regex. I'm looking for BM25 that eliminate the text length score. https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables